# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command in python

Tags: python

I'm running into a weird error when trying to install pip
This is the sequence that I typed into my command line:
pip install opencv-python
What could be causing this?

This is what I get when I type in `echo %PATH%`:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;E:\MATLAB\R2022b\bin;D:\nodejs;:\users\“naglaa“\AppData\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;E:\MATLAB\R2022b\bin;D:\nodejs;:\users\“naglaa“\AppData\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\naglaa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\naglaa`

Comment: can you share the output for `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: @JaysheelUtekar The title has the error message.

Comment: open cmd and type `where pip` and you know your pip path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`“naglaa“` in your path looks suspicious.  User names shouldn't be in quotes, and especially smart quotes.  The drive letter is missing as well: `:\users\“naglaa“\AppData\Programs\Python\Python310`.

Ideally, don't put Python in the Windows path and use `py` (the Python Launcher) as in `py -m pip install opencv-python`.  If you have multiple Pythons installed you can say `py -0` to list installed Pythons and `py -3.10 -m pip install opencv-python` to install on a specific version.

See [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pip has been added into your PATH.
Usually pip.exe is located in your "...\Python\Python310\Scripts". (You do have python added in the PATH tho since you have "...\Python\Python310" in the list).

So all you have to do is to add the existing "Scripts" folder into PATH variable and you will be good to go.